# PHP & MySQL : What's Wrong with Code to Add to a Database & Retrieve

Tags: php, mysql

It's supposed to let you add a personal link to a database, and the Server is running Windows Server 2008 R2 with MySQL & Active Directory.

```
<?php 
$dbl = mysql_connect('localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD') or die('failed to connect to mysql'); 
mysql_select_db('linksdatabase') or die('failed to select database'); 

if(isset($_POST['linkaddress']) && isset($_POST['linkname'])) 
$sql = "INSERT INTO userlinks (username, linkaddress, linkname) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')";
mysql_query ( sprintf ( $sql, mysql_real_escape_string ( $_SERVER ['AUTH_USER'] ), mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['linkaddress'] ), mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['linkname'] ) ) );

echo '<p>Links:</p><ul>'; 

$result = mysql_query ( sprintf ( "SELECT linkaddress, linkname FROM userlinks WHERE username = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string ( $_SERVER ['AUTH_USER'] ) ) );

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
    echo '<li><a href="', htmlentities($row['linkaddress']), '">', htmlentities($row['linkname']), '</a></li>'; 

echo '</ul>'; 
?> 

<form action="" method="post"> 
 <fieldset> 
  <legend>Add a Link</legend> 
  Address: <input type="text" name="linkaddress" /><br /> 
  Name: <input type="text" name="linkname" /><br /> 
  <input type="submit" value="Add" /> 
 </fieldset> 
</form>
```

Comment: Um what exactly does not work? Is there an error message? Check the return value of each `mysql_query`. Edit: your "INSERT" is missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: Some vague clues from yourself as to what's happening versus what you expect might be useful. This sort of stood out though. mysql_select_db('DATABSE NAME')

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar There aren't any error messages, it just doesn't add when I submit the form.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I've put in the server, username, password and database in the real code, I just took them out for here.

Comment: @EdCox, have you read my answer?

Comment: @EdCox: replace `mysql_query(sprintf(...))` with `mysql_query(sprintf(...)) or die("mysql_query fail: " . mysql_error())`

Comment: I didn't give either person a -1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are having some single quote `'` issues

Replace

```
   mysql_query('INSERT INTO userlinks (username, linkaddress, linkname) VALUES (\'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['AUTH_USER']) . '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['linkaddress']) . '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['linkname']) . '\'');
```

With

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO userlinks (username, linkaddress, linkname) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')";
mysql_query ( sprintf ( $sql, mysql_real_escape_string ( $_SERVER ['AUTH_USER'] ), mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['linkaddress'] ), mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['linkname'] ) ) );
```

Replace

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT linkaddress, linkname FROM userlinks WHERE username = \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['AUTH_USER']) . '\'');
```

With

```
$result = mysql_query ( sprintf ( "SELECT linkaddress, linkname FROM userlinks WHERE username = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string ( $_SERVER ['AUTH_USER'] ) ) );
```

**This code might help you to find the error**

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');

$dbl = mysql_connect ( 'localhost', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD' ) or die ( 'failed to connect to mysql' );
mysql_select_db ( 'linksdatabase' ) or die ( 'failed to select database' );

if (count ( $_POST ) < 1) {
    var_dump ( "Nothign was posted" );
} else {
    var_dump ( $_POST );
}

if (isset ( $_POST ['linkaddress'] ) && isset ( $_POST ['linkname'] )) {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO userlinks (username, linkaddress, linkname) VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')";
    mysql_query ( sprintf ( $sql, mysql_real_escape_string ( $_SERVER ['AUTH_USER'] ), mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['linkaddress'] ), mysql_real_escape_string ( $_POST ['linkname'] ) ) );

    if (mysql_errno ()) {
        var_dump ( "MySQL error " . mysql_errno () . ": " . mysql_error () );
    } else {
        var_dump ( "OK Insert" );
    }

}

echo '<p>Links:</p><ul>';

$result = mysql_query ( sprintf ( "SELECT linkaddress, linkname FROM userlinks WHERE username = '%s'", mysql_real_escape_string ( $_SERVER ['AUTH_USER'] ) ) );

if (mysql_errno ()) {
    var_dump ( "MySQL error " . mysql_errno () . ": " . mysql_error () );
} else {
    var_dump ( "OK Select" );
}

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result ) )
    echo '<li><a href="', htmlentities ( $row ['linkaddress'] ), '">', htmlentities ( $row ['linkname'] ), '</a></li>';
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: I've updated the code in the question to what I've got now, but it still doesn't work. There aren't any error messages, it just doesn't add.

Comment: Is that why you gave me a minors ?? Are you saying u did not have quote issues .. if you still have a problem then its new ... you update your question with new error not give people who are trying to help you -1

Comment: I didn't give you a -1, or the other person

Comment: Ok What is the error you are getting now .. so that i can help you resolve it ...

Comment: It doesn't give an error at all, when I submit the form it seems to work but nothing appears

Comment: Just added a new script that might help

Comment: Thanks. I had set the tables to hold interger values, not text values, and so I got [code]MySQL error 1366: Incorrect integer value: 'USERNAME' for column 'username' at row[/code], etc, but now it works great. Thanks very much.

Comment: Cool .. happy i was able to help after a rough start :D

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket `)` at the end of your query.

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO userlinks (username, linkaddress, linkname) VALUES (\'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_SERVER['AUTH_USER']) . '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['linkaddress']) . '\', \'' . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['linkname']) . '\')');
```

Comment: I didn't give you a -1, or the other person

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer, but try to line wrap when developing - makes your life easier (in the IDE) and ours (when pasting code here):

```
$sql = "
    INSERT INTO userlinks
    (username, linkaddress, linkname)
    VALUES ('%s','%s','%s')
";
mysql_query(
    sprintf(
        $sql,
        mysql_real_escape_string( $_SERVER ['AUTH_USER'] ),
        mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST ['linkaddress'] ),
        mysql_real_escape_string( $_POST ['linkname'] )
    )
);
```

This makes it easy to read everything without horizontal scrolling, and it makes checking bracket matching simple too.